# Android app relase - Facebook login button crash

Tags: android, facebook-login, android-studio-3.0

I have a problem with my app where I entered a login button with facebook.

When I use the app and on facebook developer options I have **development** mode, I have no problems,the app is working properly.

But from the moment I put it in **release** on facebook developer options, the app crashes as soon as I click on login

I've already put a key release hash on facebook developer, and I've made other attempts, but I can't understand the problem.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
        at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1749)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:984)
        at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:977)
        at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:341)
        at com.example.tpistis.tauros.LoginActivity.registra_cliente(LoginActivity.java:270)
        at com.example.tpistis.tauros.LoginActivity.apri_app(LoginActivity.java:242)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6663) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6635) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:794) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26199) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: Is your play store application is crashing or just release build is crashing?

Comment: I haven't published the app yet, I tried with signed apk

Comment: your crash log showing its an error on getting time

Comment: @unzila ye, but why is the problem present only if I put the release mode on FacebookDeveloper? and instead in develop mode I have no crashes? Where is the difference?

Comment: you updated facebook appid for release mode ???

Comment: The appid doesnt change if I switch from develop to release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who were looking for an answer, the problem was that on FacebookDevoloper I did not have the privileges to be able to acquire the date of birth, basically you can only acquire name and last name, then the app crashes.